simple postgresql query taking forever
Most of my queries are done in max 3 secs. Even if they are much more complicated. This one takes forever (at leas I quit after 10 mins):
UPDATE public.url
    SET 
        last_seen_on = NOW()
    FROM public.temp_url AS B
    INNER JOIN public.url AS A
    ON A.url_path = B.url_path;

Is there a problem with the query? I'm not getting any error messages.
EXPLAIN:
Update on url  (cost=28512.96..4035340577.80 rows=0 width=0)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=28512.96..4035340577.80 rows=188508798976 width=26)
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=28512.96..53744.52 rows=434176 width=12)
              Hash Cond: (b.url_path = a.url_path)
              ->  Seq Scan on temp_url b  (cost=0.00..12641.82 rows=434182 width=43)
              ->  Hash  (cost=19269.76..19269.76 rows=434176 width=42)
                    ->  Seq Scan on url a  (cost=0.00..19269.76 rows=434176 width=42)
        ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..23136.64 rows=434176 width=6)
              ->  Seq Scan on url  (cost=0.00..19269.76 rows=434176 width=6)
JIT:
  Functions: 13
  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true


Nobody can tell you - you haven't given any details on the size of the table, whether there are any triggers involved, clients that might be locking etc. Do run an EXPLAIN  on that though because you probably don't want the unconstrained join with the aliasing of public.url as A

Most likely this is not the query that you want, you're now updating everything. Why did you mention public.url twice? And why is there no relation between the public.url you want to update and public.temp_url?

@RichardHuxton please find my question edits. I am the only user in DB right now (it's DEV). ~500k records, but as I mention - all other queries are done in 3 secs. No triggers - this is just run by me from within DBeaver to test.

@FrankHeikens It's public.url and public.temp_url. They both have the sane columns, but some records can be deleted from temp_url. If they are I want to know when they were seen last time.

Like I said, most likely your query is wrong and it's not doing what you think it should do. Create a test with a handful of records and you'll see. Based on experience I would say you have to drop the JOIN and add a WHERE url.url_path = B.url_path

rows=188508798976, impressive... But most likely not what you intend to do.

Most likely not the correct query since you're using url twice and also without a condition.
My best bet is that you need this query:
UPDATE public.url
    SET 
        last_seen_on = NOW()
    FROM public.temp_url
WHERE url.url_path = temp_url.url_path;

An index on both columns url_path might be beneficial.

It looks like you nailed it, even even if I didn't notice it right away. Real knowledge needs to be stubborn :D Thank you.
